# how to use node() to select data from this xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

i have read some articles on Internet regrading `node()` method to extract data from xml.

i have this xml:

```xml
    <root><startsite personID="1" SaleID="2" regionID="3"/> </root>
```

i want to get personID, SaleID,region ID from the xml. What i tried is:

```
SELECT T.c.query('.') AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('/Root/startsite ') T(c)
```

but it shows me Error. Can you please help?

Comment: *"but it shows me Error."* and what is that error?

Comment: Looking at your XML, it's not valid. To parse XML, it's need to be valid XML. `personID"1"`, for example, should be `personID="1"`. Also you open 2 `root` nodes, and close neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the xml as mentioned and use the "value" method to extract the data.

```
DECLARE @x XML   
SET @x='<root><startsite personID="1" SaleID="2" regionID="3"/></root>'  

SELECT c.value('@personID', 'Int') As personID,
       c.value('@SaleID', 'Int') As SaleID,
       c.value('@regionID', 'Int') As regionID
FROM @x.nodes('/root/startsite') T(c)
```

Comment: Thankyou Anton，i am new bee with node() method. can you please explain why you use variable i.e. @personID to get result?

Comment: @Phh You are welcome! It isn't a variable. It is an attribute designation in the node.
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) is a description of XPath for a first look.

Answer (score 0):

the basic syntax is given below

```
nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)
```

The query then returns the context node from each row

```
DECLARE @x XML   
SET @x='<Root>  
    <row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row>  
    <row id="2"><name>moe</name></row>  
    <row id="3" />  
</Root>'  
SELECT T.c.query('.') AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(c)  
GO
```